Types conversion from one package to other
I'm starting with Haskell in an RSA crypto project.
Digging in Hackage, I found two different packages to achieve my objective. The problem is that each package has its own version of the same type (Same name and same fields).
To convert from one to other, I'm doing: newKey=read (show key) :: Crypto.Types.PubKey.RSA.PrivateKey
Is there a better way to convert one type from one package to the equivalent in the other package? Both types have the same name and same "fields".

That way is certainly programmer-time-efficient. The processor-time-efficient way is simply to fuse read and show, e.g.
newKey = B.Key
    { B.field1 = A.field1 key
    , B.field2 = A.field2 key
    , B.field3 = A.field3 key
    }

You might want to double-check that the meanings of the field really are the same; e.g. two ByteString fields could very well have different meanings if one is used as if it were big-endian and the other as if it were little-endian.

I wonder if case key of A{..} -> B{..} can work, under suitable assumptions, without rising ambiguity errors. Probably not.
